# Hint needed in computing a radical of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am trying to compute the radical of the following ideal:
$$
(xy^3+x^3y-x^2+y)
$$
in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

My hunch is that this ideal is radical, since it really does not seem amenable to factoring (I have tried...hard), for example, it definitely is not linearly reducible. However, I don't see why this ideal should necessarily kill a variable in the ring showing isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ or $\mathbb{C}[y]$ (which would show it is a prime ideal and therefore radical).

Please note, the above is a homework problem so I am only looking for a hint, not a solution. Any reference on methods of tackling problems like the above is welcome. I also do not know the Groebner basis method.

Comment: By considering what happens when $x=0$ and when $y=0$, I *think* that you can show that any factorization would have to look like $(1+\xi)(y-x^2+\eta)$, where $\xi,\eta\in \langle xy\rangle$. Then it should follow pretty easily that the polynomial is irreducible.